# Could make Kombu "publisher" send heartbeat to Rabbit server?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

I check the kombu 4.6 or 5.0.x code, only find the `heartbeat_check` in the `ConsumerMinxins`

https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/e3471a2fc2e3029d125b13f8ebb9299c70a19cba/kombu/mixins.py#L196

```
def consume(self, limit=None, timeout=None, safety_interval=1, **kwargs):
    elapsed = 0
    with self.consumer_context(**kwargs) as (conn, channel, consumers):
        for i in limit and range(limit) or count():
            if self.should_stop:
                break
            self.on_iteration()
            try:
                conn.drain_events(timeout=safety_interval)
            except socket.timeout:
                conn.heartbeat_check()
                elapsed += safety_interval
                if timeout and elapsed >= timeout:
                    raise
            except socket.error:
                if not self.should_stop:
                    raise
            else:
                yield
                elapsed = 0
    debug('consume exiting')
```

our RabbitMQ provided by a cloud vendor, enforced the publisher to send heartbeats, otherwise, the connection will be dropped, the producer got a "Broken Pipe" exception.